# I want to add another search box on posts page in dashboard

Tags: posts, pages, search, dashboard

There is already a search box in wordpress dashboard for posts, products, pages etc. in their listing page.

My client use wordpress admin with their phone so he requested another search box on top of those pages with the same functionality.
I can edit codes if I need to, but I don't know where to start.
Have anybody needed that kind of behavior before? It seems easy but I don't know how to edit listing pages in wordpress dashboard.

Comment: what would be the difference between the search box you want to add and the search box already present at the top of the page? It seems redundant having 2 boxes next to eachother, perhaps I've misunderstood

Comment: There will be no difference other than location in the page. Default search box appear at the bottom of page in mobile devices. It would be easier to reach it from the top. For a quick solution, I added some css to replace it. But that does not provide me with 2 search boxes, 1 at the top and 1 at the bottoom.

Comment: actually that particular search box is already at the top, it's being moved to the bottom by CSS absolute positioning. If you override the `position` parameter it moves back to the top where you're hoping. I know this doesn't answer your question but it may work as an alternative